# Jquery events not working on ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

The below code works. If there is some better way please let me know.
If i use the script content which is present in test.html in the main page where I am loading test.html through ajax. The script doesn't work.

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <script src='jquerylocation' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='ajaxload'></div>
        <button class='test'>load content via ajax</button>
    </body>


    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('.test').on('click',function(){
                  $('#ajaxload').load('test.html');
            });            
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Test.html:

```
    <h1 class='heading'>Page via AJAX</h1>

    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('.heading').on('click',function(){
                $(this).css('color','red');  
            });                          
        });
    </script>
```

we have to load the script along with dynamically loaded content through ajax to work as you require.But disadvantage I felt was each time we send ajax request script loads all the time along with content. But I found only this solution. If anyone knows better solution please reply.

For example if change the code this way it wont work.

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <script src='jquerylocation' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='ajaxload'></div>
        <button class='test'>load content via ajax</button>
    </body>


    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('.test').on('click',function(){
                  $('#ajaxload').load('test.html');
            });

            $('.heading').on('click',function(){
                $(this).css('color','red');  
            });                                   
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Test.html:

```
    <h1 class='heading'>Page via AJAX</h1>
```

Comment: it's because you're wrapping it in the document.ready function, which won't be called after an AJAX call finishes. you can try adding your event handlers in a success callback function in your load() call, or use deferred events globally defined on your main page's script section

Comment: please check my question once again I edited it. And please please reply with some code

Comment: also make sure you're defining your script tag w/the proper attributes ie `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: as per html5 DOCTYPE its fine i guess just <script></script>

Comment: some browsers dont like it though, as HTML5 is not universally implemented (or even agreed upon) yet

Comment: yeah you are right. But that might not be the problem for this question I guess.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's because you are binding the event on document ready. You have to use a delegate in order for this to work. Like [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). It's because .header isn't on the page on the page when it's loaded. So no event is attached.

Your code should look some along the lines of this:

```
$('body').on('click','.heading',function(){
     $(this).css('color','red');  
});
```

It doesn't have to be body, but an element which isn't loaded after document ready, which is a parent of *.heading*.

Comment: That is what this site is all about, glad you liked the answer! :)

Comment: Thanks, so simple, yet I was a million miles away with my own attempts. Binding to an already loaded element was key

Comment: i am braking my head since 2 days. its working grate. new lesson learned. votes up

Comment: I was always under the impression using .on is enough but certainly learnt a new thing today.. "that it should be bound to an already loaded element"..

Comment: Thank you, Peter, I spent half day with this and finally found your post.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use $(document).on("click", '.css-classname', function(event) { /// });

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $(document).on("click", '.test',function(){
                  $('#ajaxload').load('test.html');
            });

            $(document).on("click", '.heading',function(){
                $(this).css('color','red');  
            });                                   
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Worked for me, "body" did not.

Answer (score -1):

One option is to initialize your script on load success:

```
$('.test').on('click',function(){
   $('#ajaxload').load('test.html',function(){
      $('body').on('click', '.heading', function(){
          $(this).css('color','red');  
      }); 
    });
 });
```