# how to use jQuery on WordPress WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am modifying the WooCommerce checkout template files (php) so that I have additional buttons right before the "Place Order" button.

You can see the basic WooCommerce functionality on this WooCommerce demo page https://demo.woothemes.com/storefront/checkout/ if you add an item to the cart first.

I need to bind jQuery functions to the newly added buttons. Unfortunately the functions are not executed. Only if I add the buttons at a "higher level" of the template the jQuery works properly.

Are there some AJAX requests that are somehow unbinding my jQuery? How can I solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Benjamin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my question, which is here: [Jquery events not working on ajax loaded content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620211/jquery-events-not-working-on-ajax-loaded-content)

The solution is to use an on click with jQuery

```
$('body').on('click','.heading',function(){
     $(this).css('color','red');  
});
```